# Active Google API without API Console

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to active a Google Api service in php without going through the Google API Console website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which API you want to use. A few APIs, e.g. the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) do not require you to register as an application. Most APIs, especially the ones that access some user's data, however require you to setup an API project with [Google's APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), so Google knows that it is your application that accesses its API.